# Login on Safari on Mac OS X (El Capitan)

Tags: bug, login, safari

I had an little issue when loggin in with Safari on Mac OS X (El Capitan).

When entering the password in Safari, there is a key symbol that lets you choose among any password that is stored in your keychain. This button interferes with the "forgot?" button that Stack Exchange adds and you can't press the Safari button.

[image: Login on Safari]

Please move this "forgot?" button below the text field, like most other sites implement this.

Comment: The duplicate redirects here!